# How to display rows in table but skip multiple rows selection using MYSQL database

Tags: mysql

i have one table like this :

Balance Table

| id | date | item | desc | debit | credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 |  | june's balance | 50 |  |
| 2 | 2021-07-01 | Apple | sell | 10 |  |
| 3 | 2021-07-01 | Lemon | buy |  | 10 |
| 4 | 2021-07-05 | Strawberry | sell | 75 |  |
| 5 | 2021-07-05 | Strawberry | sell | 25 |  |
| 6 | 2021-07-12 | Blueberry | buy |  | 10 |
| 7 | 2021-08-01 |  | july's Balance | 140 |  |
| 8 | 2021-08-01 | Apple | sell | 25 |  |
| 9 | 2021-08-02 | Strawberry | buy |  | 5 |
| 10 | 2021-08-08 | Lemon | sell | 25 |  |
| 11 | 2021-08-27 | Lemon | sell | 35 |  |
| 12 | 2021-08-30 | Blueberry | buy |  | 20 |
| 13 | 2021-09-01 |  | aug's Balance | 200 |  |
| 14 | 2021-09-01 | Lemon | sell | 20 |  |
| 15 | 2021-09-07 | Blueberry | sell | 20 |  |
| 16 | 2021-09-07 | Strawberry | sell | 20 |  |
| 17 | 2021-09-20 | Lemon | sell | 20 |  |
| 18 | 2021-09-20 | Blueberry | sell | 20 |  |

then I added a balance column for the monthly data with query like this :

```
select t.date, t.item, t.desc, t.debit, t.credit,
  (@s := @s + t.debit - t.credit) as balance 
from balance t cross join 
  (select @s := 0) p where MONTH(t.date) = 7 //for july
order by t.date
```

and the result is as follows :

July results

| date | item | desc | debit | credit | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-01 |  | June's Balance | 50 |  | 50 |
| 2021-07-01 | apple | sell | 10 |  | 60 |
| 2021-07-01 | lemon | buy |  | 10 | 50 |
| 2021-07-05 | strawberry | sell | 75 |  | 125 |
| 2021-07-06 | strawberry | sell | 25 |  | 150 |
| 2021-07-12 | blueberry | buy |  | 10 | 140 |

August results

| date | item | desc | debit | credit | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-01 |  | July's Balance | 140 |  | 140 |
| 2021-08-01 | apple | sell | 25 |  | 165 |
| 2021-08-02 | strawberry | buy |  | 5 | 160 |
| 2021-08-08 | lemon | sell | 25 |  | 185 |
| 2021-08-27 | lemon | sell | 35 |  | 220 |
| 2021-08-30 | blueberry | buy |  | 20 | 200 |

and September results

| date | item | desc | debit | credit | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-01 |  | Aug's Balance | 200 |  | 200 |
| 2021-09-01 | lemon | sell | 20 |  | 220 |
| 2021-09-07 | blueberry | sell | 20 |  | 240 |
| 2021-09-07 | strawberry | sell | 20 |  | 260 |
| 2021-09-20 | lemon | sell | 20 |  | 280 |
| 2021-09-20 | blueberry | sell | 20 |  | 300 |

the question is, how to get a table like below, where the desc row used is only June's Balance without July's Balance and Aug's Balance.. thanks for the help

| date | item | desc | debit | credit | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-01 |  | June's Balance | 50 |  | 50 |
| 2021-07-01 | apple | sell | 10 |  | 60 |
| 2021-07-01 | lemon | buy |  | 10 | 50 |
| 2021-07-05 | strawberry | sell | 75 |  | 125 |
| 2021-07-06 | strawberry | sell | 25 |  | 150 |
| 2021-07-12 | blueberry | buy |  | 10 | 140 |
| 2021-08-01 | apple | sell | 25 |  | 165 |
| 2021-08-02 | strawberry | buy |  | 5 | 160 |
| 2021-08-08 | lemon | sell | 25 |  | 185 |
| 2021-08-27 | lemon | sell | 35 |  | 220 |
| 2021-08-30 | blueberry | buy |  | 20 | 200 |
| 2021-09-01 | lemon | sell | 20 |  | 220 |
| 2021-09-07 | blueberry | sell | 20 |  | 240 |
| 2021-09-07 | strawberry | sell | 20 |  | 260 |
| 2021-09-20 | lemon | sell | 20 |  | 280 |
| 2021-09-20 | blueberry | sell | 20 |  | 300 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I partially loaded up a table in [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/25iC49PE1SPezgvkKz4D9n/1).

This will display the running balances with whatever starting month you choose ('2021-07-01' in this case):

```sql
select t.date,
       ifnull(t.item, '') as item,
       t.desc,
       ifnull(t.debit, 0) as debit,
       ifnull(t.credit, 0) as credit,
       (@s := @s + ifnull(t.debit, 0) - ifnull(t.credit, 0)) as balance 
from balance t cross join (select @s := 0) p
where t.date >= '2021-07-01' and (t.date = '2021-07-01' or t.item is not null)
order by t.date
```

| date | desc | item | debit | credit | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-01 | june's balance |  | 50 | 0 | 50 |
| 2021-07-01 | sell | Apple | 10 | 0 | 60 |
| 2021-07-01 | buy | Lemon | 0 | 10 | 50 |
| 2021-07-05 | sell | Strawberry | 75 | 0 | 125 |
| 2021-08-01 | sell | Apple | 25 | 0 | 150 |
| 2021-08-02 | buy | Strawberry | 0 | 5 | 145 |
| 2021-08-08 | sell | Lemon | 25 | 0 | 170 |

---

Comment: Yes,... this is exactly what I was looking for... thanks bro.. works perfectly

Comment: When I try in db fiddle it works perfectly, but when I try in mysql database script your script keeps displaying July's Balance and Aug's Balance.. What's wrong?

Comment: Is the `item` column `NULL` for those rows which have closing balances in the `desc` column, for example `September's Balance`?

Comment: I Fix it... now it can run into mysql databases.. thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

You could adapt your where clause to exclude all Balances that aren't in the start date.

But your concept doesn't include years, which you must include, when the considered time line goes over a year

> ```
> select t.`date`, t.item, t.desc, t.debit, t.credit,
>   (@s := IFNULL(@s,0) + IFNULL(t.debit,0) - IFNULL(t.credit,0)) as balance 
> from balance t cross join 
>   (select @s := 0) p 
> where (`desc`  LIKE '% Balance' AND MONTH(t.date) = (SELECT MIN(MONTH(`date`)) FROM balance)) or `desc` NOT LIKE '% Balance'
> order by t.`date`
> ```
>
> ```
> date       | item       | desc           | debit | credit | balance
> :--------- | :--------- | :------------- | :---- | :----- | ------:
> 2021-07-01 | null       | june's balance | 50    | null   |      50
> 2021-07-01 | Apple      | sell           | 10    | null   |      60
> 2021-07-01 | Lemon      | buy            | null  | 10     |      50
> 2021-07-05 | Strawberry | sell           | 75    | null   |     125
> 2021-07-05 | Strawberry | sell           | 25    | null   |     150
> 2021-07-12 | Blueberry  | buy            | null  | 10     |     140
> 2021-08-01 | Apple      | sell           | 25    | null   |     165
> 2021-08-02 | Strawberry | buy            | null  | 5      |     160
> 2021-08-08 | Lemon      | sell           | 25    | null   |     185
> 2021-08-27 | Lemon      | sell           | 35    | null   |     220
> 2021-08-30 | Blueberry  | buy            | null  | 20     |     200
> 2021-09-01 | Lemon      | sell           | 20    | null   |     220
> 2021-09-07 | Blueberry  | sell           | 20    | null   |     240
> 2021-09-07 | Strawberry | sell           | 20    | null   |     260
> 2021-09-20 | Lemon      | sell           | 20    | null   |     280
> 2021-09-20 | Blueberry  | sell           | 20    | null   |     300
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e51ece4e91066688cc3388f982baf6c4)*